# Powershell New-SelfSignedCertificate script error 0x80090029

Tags: powershell, self-signed-certificate

so, i'm using the method in powershell `New-SelfSignedCertificate` to get a certificate, when i type `New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "Flock os ████ ████████" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3") -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2032 -FriendlyName "Flock Os signed script from quality managment department " -NotAfter 12-31-2032`
Powershell gives me

`New-SelfSignedCertificate : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: The requested operation is not supported.
0x80090029 (-2146893783 NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED)
At line:1 char:2

- New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "Flock os ████ ████████" -TextExt ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], Exception
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
  ```

can somone help me with the correct command?

Comment: Try omitting the `-KeyLength` parameter (defaults to 2048 for `RSA`).

Comment: @JosefZ so... the -NotAfter comand woud be a replacement for -KeyLength?

Comment: [`-NotAfter` Specifies the date and time, as a DateTime object, that the certificate expires. To obtain a DateTime object, use the `Get-Date` cmdlet.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2019-ps&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

RSA key sizes in use today are 2048 and 4096.
You need to change value for your `-KeyLength` parameter to 2048